# Markov chains ordening

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

I cannot solve this problem. Does anyone know how I can solve it? I already have my state space and transition matrix.

Problem: Each morning, a student takes one of the three books (labelled 1,2 and 3) from her shelf. She choose book i with probability alpha_i, and choices on successive days are independent. In the evening, she replaces the book at the left-hand end of the shelf. If p_n denotes the probability that on day n she find the books in the order 1,2,3 from left to right, show that p_n converges as n goes to infinity, and find the limit.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you figured out the states and written down the transition matrix?

Comment: Well i have my state space and transition matrix. And here i get stucked ;(

Comment: If you have them, you should add them to your question. This shows you have made some effort (which means you are more likely to get help), and we can also see whether or not you are on the right track and give the appropriate hints/help.

Comment: @smcc that is true. Thank you. I will do it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: $X_t=$the order of the books in the morning

so, $\Pr(X_{t+1}=1,2,3|X_t=3,2,1)=0$, $\Pr(X_{t+1}=1,2,3|X_t=2,1,3)=\alpha_1$, and so on

Comment: Yes i already figured that out. That is how i got my  transition matrix. But my problem is that I am now stucked :(

Comment: sorry, until what point you got stuck? you dont know how to calculate the limiting prbability?

Comment: yes that is where I got stucked :)

Comment: do you know this formula? $\pi_j=\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i P_{ij}$, where $S$ is the states set, so you will get system of linear equations, before you solve that, you have to choose one equation and replace that with $\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i=1$